# Unable to get dependency from nexus. Showing version as null on console but version is set

Tags: java, maven, jar, nexus

Its trying to get some spring framework Jar files, and they are definitely in the nexus. On the Maven Install output, it says the version is null, but it is specified as 3.1.2.RELEASE.

Below is the output from the Maven install:

```
No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [2.5.2,3)
org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:null
```

The dependency is in the pom.xml as shown below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you edit in your question your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Change the upper bound of the range to something that includes 3.1.2, such as 3.9.9